# Google App Script - compare and copy data (URL Redirect list)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please, do you have any idea how to solve the following work-flow in Google Spreadsheets or in JavaScript?

1) I have a list(sheet) of old URLs (1 URL per row)

2) I have a list(sheet) of new URLs (1 URL per row) which I want to pair to old similar URLs (for 301 redirect)

3) I have selected from URLs part of string which could be used for search and pair

4) I need to search the string in the list of new URLs and if there is a match, I need to copy this new URL and copy and paste it to the new column (D) next to the old URL.

[image: image of table]

I have tried google and lots of Google Spreadsheets Add-ons, but I cannot find anything that works.

I have the idea of the algorithm, but no clue how to write it in Google App Script (and the documentation didn't help)

1) for loop to select data from each row in column B

2) another for loop to select each row in column F

3) compare, if the data from step 1 is inside any cell in column F (for loop from step 2)

4) if there is a match, copy the cell from column F to column D, next to the substring which it found

Please, any ideas how to make it work?

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function redirectSearch() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Redirect');
  var rng=sht.getRange(2,1,sht.getLastRow(),sht.getLastColumn());
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var substringA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)//load the substring Array
  {
    substringA.push(rngA[i][1]);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<substringA.length;j++)
    {
      if(String(rngA[i][3]).indexOf(substringA[j])>-1)//look for substring in all of the new urls
      {
        rngA[j][2]=rngA[i][3];//if found copy them to column C next to substring
      }
    }
  }
  rng.setValues(rngA);//reload results and original data
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is perfect! I will have to learn this language too :) Thanks again for your great help man.

Comment: I'm glad to help.